# managing AspNetIdentity DbContext in n-tier application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, dbcontext, asp.net-identity-2

Hi. I’m working on a solution which consists of layered mvc application using entity framework. I want to use AspNet Identity to manage user accounts and logins. Which has its own model and dbcontext classes embedded in it and all of these are inside my UI MVC project.

But I don’t want this. I want to be able to manage my database interactions through data layer which is entity framework and my own DB context. Now for a simple user account in order to be related with my custom Person class, I should do two separate database insert commands. One for create user and one for its related person object. I did merged two separate databases as one, but for contexts I still don’t know what to do.

Am I in the right direction or I’m missing something? Is there any best practices for this type of problems? I’m sure this has been solved for many people but I can’t figure it out how. I searched around for solutions on this problem but I couldn’t find anything useful. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried inheriting your context from IdentityDbContext?